# Tests for javascript compliance with unusual variable names

Tags: javascript

Have any tests been done across many browsers/rendering engines to check they adhere to the javascript spec in relation to variable names including unusual characters.

For example, if I use...

```
π = Math.PI
truth = "Pi should really be "+(2*π)+" and a lot of maths should be re-written"
```

I know the spec says it should work - but do all javascript interpreters follow perfectly the spec?

If that works in firefox, can I expect it to work in internet explorer too - on all platforms? And will it also work on Rhino, or other javascript interpreters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [first edition of ecmascript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf), dating back to june 1997, they are not allowed:

> Non-ASCII Unicode characters may appear only within comments and string literals

In the [third edition of ecmascript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf), dating back to december 1999, they are allowed:

> Non-Latin Unicode characters are allowed in identifiers, string literals, regular expression literals and comments.

So anything that claims to implement > es3, will support them.